# Get sub-value from key in multidimensional JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I've been pulling my hair out for days now and I guess I just don't see it anymore. Hopefully others may have the solution which should be simpler than I think :-/

I have this JSON code:

```
{  
   "status":"success",
   "data":{  
      "first_name":"Paul",
      "custom_fields":[  
         {  
            "id":55112,
            "name":"EmailSoSoLead",
            "type":"text",
            "description":"",
            "value":"huh@gmail.com"
         },
         {  
            "id":55113,
            "name":"TelNrSoSoLead",
            "type":"number",
            "description":"",
            "value":4654566465456
         },
         {  
            "id":116162,
            "name":"OrderAmount",
            "type":"number",
            "description":"",
            "value":6956
         },
      ],
      "tags":[  
         {  
            "id":1705169,
            "name":"RealtorLeadComplete"
         },
         {  
            "id":3542812,
            "name":"cbs_trialcode_received"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I'm trying to get the emailaddress from the custom field.

I tried just about all i could find.

Getting the tags was easy, but i have trouble with the specific custom fields.

```
foreach($json_obj->data->custom_fields as $mc_uid_cuf_data)
{
    foreach($mc_uid_cuf_data as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $key . ': ' . $value;
        ...
```

That works fine and prints all nicely. But I need the specific ones.

I tried:

```
if (in_array('EmailSoSoLead', $mc_uid_cuf_data)) {
```

and this

```
if ($key == "name" && $value == "EmailSoSoLead")
      $email = $json_obj->data->custom_fields->value;
```

My JSON is decoded as objects, not associative arrays:

```
$json_obj          = json_decode($server_output);
```

To be honest I've been trying so much now I am basically shooting blanks now, too puzzled. Anybody?

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are testing one property and then trying to get the value of another but they are all in an array.

Capture the index of the outer loop and use that in the addressing of the email you are trying to capture like this for example

```
foreach($json_obj->data->custom_fields as $occ => $mc_uid_cuf_data) {
    foreach($mc_uid_cuf_data as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . ': ' . $value;

        if ($key == "name" && $value == "EmailSoSoLead") 
            $email = $json_obj->data->custom_fields[$occ]->value;
        ...
```

Comment: Awesome, so all that was missing was the $occ section;-)
Thanks fo rhelping me out!